# How to properly use nodejs modules on a capacitor aplication. Testing on welcome build

Tags: node.js, capacitor, welcome-file

I've being trying to build an application that would run on capacitor and would also supports nodejs modules, so I could eventually use some of them on android.
But first I'm trying to make them working on a desktop.

To test an initial build, I've read the [getting-started section of the capacitor documentation](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/getting-started). And modify it slightly to work with two modules that I'll probably used in the future, those are `json5` and `path`.

Following the documentation, I've used the welcome build available by typing:

```
npm init @capacitor/app
```

Then I modified the file created at `src/js/capacitor-welcome.js`. Since `require()` wasn't working I used the `import` keyword

```
import { SplashScreen } from '@capacitor/splash-screen';
import { Camera } from '@capacitor/camera';
import json5 from 'json5'
// import path from 'path' // will broke the page

window.customElements.define(
  'capacitor-welcome',
  class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();

      console.log("json5 is building normally")
      console.log(json5)
      console.log("path isn't")
      // console.log(path)

// ... rest of the code
```

Import the necessary modules:

```
npm i json5
npm i path
```

And then proceed to build and previewing it on my browser:

```
npx vite build
npx vite preview
```

By removing the comment of the path import, you can see how it breaks the page.

Is there a way to universally build all modules just like a `require('path')` would do in the context of nodejs?
Should I differ my strategy entirely?

Comment: You can’t use nodejs packages in capacitor apps. You can only use npm packages that support browser, not nodejs.